# iOS - Can't set the container view content using prepareforsegue

Tags: ios, uicontainerview

I have a UIViewController , there are three container view link same embed UIViewController(ContainerViewController).

[image]

Then the segue identifier with "segue1","segue2","segue3".

I was set the value in the prepareForSegue, But there are not changed UILabel(currentLB) in the container view.

I set the code in the UIViewController.m

```
 -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
     NSLog(@"segue.identifier:%@",segue.identifier);
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue1"]) {
          ContainerViewController *viewController = (ContainerViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
         viewController.currentLB.text = @"123";
     }
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue2"]) {
         ContainerViewController *viewController = (ContainerViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
         viewController.currentLB.text = @"234";
     }
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue3"]) {
         ContainerViewController *viewController = (ContainerViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
         viewController.currentLB.text = @"345";
     }

 }
```

Have anyone know why?

I know there are other method use

```
((ContainerViewController*)self.childViewControllers[1]).currentLB.text = @"2222";
```

can set the container value.

But I want the using the prepareforsegue to set value now.

Have anyone know what wrong ?

thank you very much.

----answer----

In the UIViewContainer.h set the NSString property.

```
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *containerLBValue;
```

in the UIViewContainer.m
     -(void)viewDidLoad
     {
         [super viewDidLoad];

```
     self.currentLB.text = self.containerLBValue;
 }
```

Change the prepareForSegue code:

```
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue1"]) {
     ContainerViewController *viewController =      (ContainerViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
    viewController.containerLBValue = @"123";
     }
```

Comment: is your prepareForSegue code ever called ? I'm running into an issue where prepareForSegue is not called when using "embed segue"

Comment: Yes, It will call when I enter this uiviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the text of an IBOutlet in prepareForSegue, because the view has not been loaded yet, and the outlets will be nil. You need to have a string property in the destination controller, and pass the string to it. The destination controller should then set its own label in viewDidLoad using this passed in string.